# Recursive Cte to find Min and Max related data's in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group, recursive-query

I have a below kind of data in my table and i need to get the below kind of output.

```
U.Id  Current_Id  Previous_Id Date reason values
01        aa          null     21   xyz    V1
01        bb           aa      24   yxz    V2
01        cc           bb      24   out    V3
01        dd           cc      25   tot    V4
01        aaa         null     11   yyz    VV4
01        bbb         aaa      12   zyy    VV3
```

First four records are one set and next two records are one set. we can identify this by current_id and Previous_ID columns. I need below kind of Output.

Output :

```
O1 - aa - 21 - 25 - tot - V4
01 - aaa - 11 - 12 -zyy - VV3
```

For each set i need first record date and last record date,value,reason. How can i achieve this in ms sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select uid, current_id, previous_id, date, value, date first_date, current_id first_id, 1 lvl
    from mytable 
    where previous_id is null
    union all
    select t.uid, t.current_id, t.previous_id, t.date, c.first_date, c.first_id, c.lvl + 1
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.previous_id = c.current_id and t.uid = c.uid
)
select uid, first_id, first_date, date last_date, reason last_reason, value last_value
from cte c
where c.lvl = (select max(c1.lvl) from cte c1 where c1.first_id = c.first_id and c1.uid = c.uid)
```

The recursive query iteratively walks the hierarchy starting from the root notes (identified by a `null` value in column `previous_id`), while keeping track of the first `date` and `id`. Then, the outer query filters on the last record per tree.